# Session in Laravel 5.4.3 doesn't works

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have a problem with session in laravel ,
In localhost works fine , but in shared hosting (webhostingworld) dosen't work
Same code.
This is the code in session.php

```
<?php
return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,   
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => null,   
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',  
    'domain' => '',
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
    'http_only' => true,

];
```

This is the code in web.php

```
Route::get('/put',function(){
    Session::put('test','testing');
    return Session::get('test'); //here returning testing
});
Route::get('/get',function(){
    return Session::get('test'); //but here return empty result
});
```

Server PHP Version 5.6.31 , SSH access is not possible to shared host

Comment: Check permissions at `storage`, if you are using linux: `chmod -R a+rw storage/`

Comment: storage permission 777 @Troyer

Comment: do you have any files in storage directory ?

Comment: there are app, framework, logs folders @DanMiller

Comment: Sorry. I meant in session storage path. `framework/sessions`

Comment: @Gunel, As said, check permission on storage folders (and subdirectories). `storage`, `storage/framework` and `storage/framework/sessions`

Comment: All have 777 permission @okante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was found, i have created settings.php file for uploading images specific folders, after deleting that file from hosting  session worked